# How to extract UI elements from XCODE?

Tags: xcode, image

I'm looking to get a PNG (or other image format supporting alpha transparency) version of the UI builder (sliders, togglers, buttons etc.) elements from XCODE. Does anyone know how to do this/where the files containing these are located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are looking for GUI kits in the form of PSDs...

If yes, check this handy link http://speckyboy.com/2010/04/30/iphone-and-ipad-development-gui-kits-stencils-and-icons/

The author has linked to various resources available on the net.
Hope this answers your question.